# Android ThreadPool and BlockingQueue problems

Tags: android, threadpool

so I have created a singleton of threadpool:

threadpool.java

```
package utils;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

public class TaskManager {

    // Sets the amount of time an idle thread will wait for a task before
// terminating
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE_TIME = 30;

// Sets the Time Unit to seconds
private static final TimeUnit KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT;

private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 2;

private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 2;

// A queue of Runnable for the image download pool
private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> mTaskQueue;

// A managed pool of background download threads
private final ThreadPoolExecutor mTaskThreadPool;

private static TaskManager sInstance = null;

private Handler mHandler;

// A static block that sets class fields

static {
    // The time unit for "keep alive" is in seconds
    KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT = TimeUnit.SECONDS;

    // Creates a single static instance of PhotoManager
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new TaskManager();
        Log.d("init", "new TaskManager");
    }

}

public Handler getHandler() {
    return mHandler;
}

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private TaskManager() {
    mTaskQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();

    mTaskThreadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE,
            MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT,
            mTaskQueue);

    mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message m) {
            switch (m.what) {
            case 0:
                Log.d("start", (String) m.obj);
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.d("finish", (String) m.obj);
                break;
            }
        }
    };
}

public static TaskManager getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
}

public void addTask(Runnable task) {
    sInstance.mTaskQueue.offer(task);
    Log.d("size after add", Integer.toString(sInstance.mTaskQueue.size()));
}

public void startTask() {
    if (!sInstance.mTaskQueue.isEmpty()) {
        sInstance.mTaskThreadPool.execute(sInstance.mTaskQueue.poll());
        Log.d("size after start", Integer.toString(sInstance.mTaskQueue.size()));
    } else
        Log.d("queue empty", "yes");
        return;
}
}
```

in another class I have a button,

let's say everytime I click that **button**, it will call in order:

- `TaskManager.getinstance().addTask(task)`
- `TaskManager.getinstance().startTask();`

so I click this button once, and everything seems normal,

but if I click this once more after all tasks are done,

`Log.d("queue empty", "yes");` will be executed,

my question is, I don't really understand what happens to the **BlockingQueue** inside this singleton, can anyone explain? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about this on Android specifically, but from the [standard Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) it looks like you're using the `BlockingQueue` and `ThreadPoolExecutor` incorrectly.  You should not add tasks to the `BlockingQueue` directly.  The "Queue Maintenance" section of the class documentation for the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class and [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getQueue%28%29) for the `getQueue()` method indicate that you should not interact with the queue.

Instead you should add tasks using the `submit()` method on the `ExecutorService` interface.  This will queue the task and start the execution as soon as a thread is available.  [Here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/using-threadpoolexecutor-to-parallelize.html) is an article with some further examples.

To fix, delete the `addTask()` method and modify `startTask()` to the following:

```
public Future<Void> startTask(Runnable task) {
    return mTaskThreadPool.submit(task);
}
```

This will also allow you to cancel the task through the returned Future.  To cancel the task call [`Future::cancel(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29).

Comment: great, thanks for your answer, but now I have another question, let's say I want to remove one runnable inside that `BlockingQueue`, do you have any idea how? thanks

Comment: Are you trying to remove a specific task or just one task on the queue?

Comment: ThreadExecutor has a `remove()` method which takes a task to remove.  You would have to store the task somewhere else so that you could pass it to `remove()`.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: so I have few buttons, that will pass Runnable object, then if I click  one of button twice, it will remove Runnable object from `ThreadPool`, is that possible?

Comment: I assume you are trying to implement some sort of cancelation mechanism.  It's not going to be as simple as just calling remove.  I am guessing that if the task has already started, remove will not cancel.  You will probably have to implement a check in the task execution for cancelation.

Comment: yes I am, do you have any article or recommended reading relates to threadpool? I really appreciate your help

Comment: Ok, I was wrong it is easier than I thought.  Just use submit() instead of execute() .  This returns a Future which you can use to cancel the task.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

apparently after all tasks are done,

the ThreadPool is still active and will immediately fetch all new tasks given , which added to TaskQueue,

and it will automatically make Queue empty ,

and if given tasks are more than `MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE` available thread, it will start queuing tasks again...